# Use of scikit Random Forest sample_weights

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I've been trying to figure out scikit's Random Forest sample_weight use and I cannot explain some of the results I'm seeing. Fundamentally I need it to balance a classification problem with unbalanced classes.

In particular, I was expecting that if I used a sample_weights array of all 1's I would get the same result as `w sample_weights=None`. Additionally, I was expeting that any array of equal weights (i.e. all 1s, or all 10s or all 0.8s...) would provide the same result. Perhaps my intuition of weights is wrong in this case.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import ensemble,metrics, cross_validation, datasets

#create a synthetic dataset with unbalanced classes
X,y = datasets.make_classification(
n_samples=10000, 
n_features=20, 
n_informative=4, 
n_redundant=2, 
n_repeated=0, 
n_classes=2, 
n_clusters_per_class=2, 
weights=[0.9],
flip_y=0.01,
class_sep=1.0, 
hypercube=True, 
shift=0.0, 
scale=1.0, 
shuffle=True, 
random_state=0)

model = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()

w0=1 #weight associated to 0's
w1=1 #weight associated to 1's

#I should split train and validation but for the sake of understanding sample_weights I'll skip this step
model.fit(X, y,sample_weight=np.array([w0 if r==0 else w1 for r in y]))    
preds = model.predict(X)
probas = model.predict_proba(X)
ACC = metrics.accuracy_score(y,preds)
precision, recall, thresholds = metrics.precision_recall_curve(y, probas[:, 1])
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, probas[:, 1])
ROC = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(y,preds)
print "ACCURACY:", ACC
print "ROC:", ROC
print "F1 Score:", metrics.f1_score(y,preds)
print "TP:", cm[1,1], cm[1,1]/(cm.sum()+0.0)
print "FP:", cm[0,1], cm[0,1]/(cm.sum()+0.0)
print "Precision:", cm[1,1]/(cm[1,1]+cm[0,1]*1.1)
print "Recall:", cm[1,1]/(cm[1,1]+cm[1,0]*1.1)
```

- With `w0=w1=1` I get, for instance, `F1=0.9456`.
- With `w0=w1=10` I get, for instance, `F1=0.9569`.
- With `sample_weights=None` I get `F1=0.9474`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the Random Forest algorithm, there is, as the name implies, some "Random"ness to it.

You are getting different F1 score because the Random Forest Algorithm (RFA) is using a subset of your data to generate the decision trees, and then averaging across all of your trees. I am not surprised, therefore, that you have similar (but non-identical) F1 scores for each of your runs.

I have tried balancing the weights before. You may want to try balancing the weights by the size of each class in the population. For example, if you were to have two classes as such:

```
Class A: 5 members
Class B: 2 members
```

You may wish to balance the weights by assigning 2/7 for each of `Class A`'s members and 5/7 for each of `Class B`'s members. That's just an idea as a starting place, though. How you weight your classes will depend on the problem you have.

Comment: Once I set a seed for the random forest, things started making sense.

Comment: If you want to set class weights, you should just use `class_weight` optional parameter in the `RandomForestClassifier` initialization.  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html