# scikit-learn weighted multiclass classification

Tags: scikit-learn

How to tune multiclass classifier to be more accurate with some classes than others(if training dataset contains both classes in equal amount). I want to manage precision weights according to class.
For example:
5 classes but I wan't 1st and 2nd classes prediction to be more accurate then for others.
P.S.:
I'm using RandomizedForest classifier. SVC is not appropriate at the moment.

Comment: This issue has been addressed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418606/use-of-scikit-random-forest-sample-weights

Comment: Thanks I've seen that before.